# mac os x how to add files to core data database

Tags: macos, core-data, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I want to storage images and the core data database of my app but I can not figure out how to add the images to my core data data base. By any chance any of you knows how can I do this?. I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This can by done by using a Binary Data attribute on your entity. This allows you to store binary data (such as images or files) directly in a core data database. If the files/images are expected to be over 10MB, I would check the "Allows External Storage" checkbox in the attribute inspector for your binary data attribute. This allows core data to store this data in a file external to your .sqlite file. This helps with fetching/saving efficiency, but if you have a heavy load of images/files, you're better off managing the files yourself. Core Data isn't optimized for large blobs of data.

Comment: I would recommend checking that box for any binary attribute, regardless of what you expect the size to be. It allows using external files but doesn't require it, so let Core Data decide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add images as binary data, `NSData`.

But this is not efficient to handle. Better way to save the images as file and then store the file name in the database. This will save the query overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a Transformable attribute which will handle the transformation to and from NSImage automatically. Bear in mind if you want images to be compatible with iOS you best stick with PNG format.